# Memcached can't connect on Windows 7 via PHP

Tags: php, windows, memcached

On one computer with Windows 7 connecting to memcache runs OK, but on another I get:

> Warning: memcache_connect() [function.memcache-connect]: Can't connect to localhost:11211

Code which I'm trying to run is:

```
$memcache_obj = memcache_connect('localhost', 11211);
```

I also can't connect via telnet, a failed connection.

Comment: can you enable telnet/ or use putty, try telnet localhost 11211?

Comment: I tried but seems to there is no telnet on that computer

Comment: OK now i have telnet i will try connect via it

Comment: I get message about failed connection...

Answer (score 1):

start>run type CMD , in the console window type `netstat -a -n` , do you see something like `0.0.0.0:11211 ... LISTENING` ? , if no , probably memcached is not running , or is configured to another port .

In the console , try `c:\memcached\memcached.exe -d start` 'supposing you have memcached installed in `c:\memcached` .

to run memcached as windows service , try `memcached.exe –d install` .

YOU SHOULD START THE CONSOLE AS AN ADMINISTRATOR . try `start>all programs > Accessories` , then right click on `command prompt` and run as administrator , then apply all of the above

Answer (score 0):

Memcached is either not running on the machine that you can't connect on or the instance of memcached running on that machine is configured to use a different port.

If you don't have (or want) an instance of memcached one each machine you will need to change "localhost" to the IP of the machine that is running memcached (assuming they are networked).

If it is set up try starting memcached again, and ensure you're using port 11211.